# Is there a way to find the average precision and recall of each class in the custom Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have trained a model using TensorFlow and SSD MobileNet. I was able to find the mean average precision of the model. Is their a way to find the average precision of each class in the models.
I am using Tensorflow 2.5 version.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use sklearn  per the code below. For both the confusion matrix and the classification report you need to provide y_predict and y_true. After you train you model then do predictions on the test set. Somewhere I assume you have y_true in your code as the label for the classes. I will assume they are present in a list called y_true and are in the SAME order as your inputs to model.predict. I will also assume you have a list called classes which are the names of your classes in order.
For example if cats is label 0 and dogs is label 1 then classes=[cats, dogs]

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
preds=model.predict ---etc
ypredict=[]
for p in preds:
    index=np.argmax(p)
    y_predict.append(index)
y_true= np.array(y_true)        
y_predict=np.array(y_predict)    
# create a confusion matrix 
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predict ) 
# code below formats the confusion matrix plot       
length=len(classes)
if length<8:
    fig_width=8
    fig_height=8
 else:
    fig_width= int(length * .5)
    fig_height= int(length * .5)
plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
plt.xticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation= 90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
plt.xlabel("Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Actual")
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.show()
clr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=classes)
print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)
```

Below is an example of a classification report

```
Classification Report:
----------------------
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

      Banana       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
       Bread       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
        Eggs       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
        Milk       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
       Mixed       1.00      1.00      1.00        12
      Potato       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
     Spinach       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
      Tomato       1.00      1.00      1.00        15

    accuracy                           1.00       117
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       117
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       117
```

Comment: Really thanks for the response. Actually i am a beginer and I have seen where the y_true and y_pred are initialized in the code. it is inside the "models\research\object_detection\metrics\calibration_evaluation.py". But how to fetch that values. How to initialitze those. Do you have any idea?

Comment: sorry I do not understand your question

Comment: How to get the y_pred and y_true values from my custom model?. I have created an object detection model with 3 classes using the Network, SSD MobileNet, So from the trained model, and the parameters, How can I get the y_pred value and x_pred value